# Digraph weak connectivity in $O(V)$ space and $O(V+E)$ time

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, directed-graphs

A digraph is called *weakly connected* if its underlying undirected graph is connected.

You are given a digraph $G$ with $V$ vertices and $E$ edges as a read-only data structure consisting of lists of the out-neighbours of each vertex. You are also given $O(V)$ words of working memory, where a word is just large enough to hold an integer of magnitude $O(E)$.

Can you test $G$ for weak connectivity in $O(V+E)$ time?

Note that you are not given lists of the in-neighbours of each vertex and you don't have enough space to construct them.

Using the standard union-find algorithm, it can be done in $O(V+E\,\alpha(E))$ time for $\alpha$ being some Ackermann function inverse. Can you do better?

Comment: I would love an answer to this in either direction.  If it's not getting attention here, maybe it should be migrated to cstheory?